# Meaning of representation

Tags: representation-theory

In mathematics, what does it mean by "one object is represented by another object"?

Here is my guess. Given a mapping $f: X\to Y$. If $f$ preserves some structures when mapping from $X$ to $Y$, then is it that $X$ is a representation of $Y$, or $Y$ is a representation of $X$?

Do we need $f$ to be injective?

[For example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-parameter_semigroup),

> Formally, a strongly continuous semigroup $ T : \mathbb{R}_+ \to L(X) $ is a **representation** of the semigroup $(\mathbb R+,+)$ on some Banach space $X$ that is continuous in the strong operator topology. Thus, strictly speaking, a strongly continuous semigroup is not a semigroup, but rather a continuous representation of a very particular semigroup.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation (or more in general http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory#Definition ).

When $f$ is injective, the representation is called **faithful**. Depending on the context, you may or may not want to consider such representations.

Formally, the representation is the map $f$. I think is usually accepted to refer to the image of $f$ as the "representation" of $X$.